# How to compare two NSDates in a for loop

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I want this code below to do what's in the for loop as long as **checkDate** is less than or equal to ( <=) **periodEnd**  (**checkDate** must be between **periodStart** and **periodEnd**).

```
    for(checkDate = period.periodStart; [checkDate compare: period.periodEnd] ==  NSOrderedDescending;
    checkDate = [checkDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:timeInterval])  {

    [self addAppointmentsForDate:checkDate scheduleSet:setOfSchedules appointmentSet:setOfAppts];

}
```

It never executes the body of the for loop... this is the data it's working with:

[image]

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?  I've looked in Google and SO for examples , but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the for loop should be checking if the comparison is **ascending** instead, meaning that checkDate is less than periodEnd

As you can see from the documentation of the `compare:` method :

> **Return value**
>
> if:
>
> `...`
>
> The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, `NSOrderedAscending`.

Comment: Another way to do it is to take `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` on both dates and then compare with `>` or `<` as desired.  This is a lot clearer and likely no less efficient.

Comment: The only one I didn't try!  Thank you... I appreciate it.  :D

Comment: Also, for one project I wrote a category on NSDate with `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods, so that one didn't have to spend so much time thinking about it (and half the time thinking wrong).

Comment: @HotLicks that reminds me of the [NSComparisonMethods protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) on OS X.